# How to put write if statement for getDisplayName() if user didn't login yet?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I got this problem while running my apps:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getDisplayName() on a null object reference

I want to make an app that user can browse without the need to login first.
How to put the `name.setText("hi, " + currentUser.getDisplayName());` inside if statement what should i write in the coding of if statement ?

This is my `MainActivity` java class:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name=findViewById(R.id.name);

    //        //display customer's account name
    name.setText("hi, " + currentUser.getDisplayName());

    //ini
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cust");



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_option,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id= item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.logout){
        logout();
        return true;
    }
    else if (id==R.id.login){
        login();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void login() {
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

private void logout() {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if currentUser is not null:

```
if (currentUser != null) name.setText("hi, " + currentUser.getDisplayName());
```

But also, in your code, you ask for `getDisplayName` **before** you initialise it from firebase so it will allways be null:

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cust");

if (currentUser != null) name.setText("hi, " + currentUser.getDisplayName());
```

Comment: Call ```firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();``` before you use ```currentUser```. You can keep the null check incase there is no user logged in.